# Непонятная error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.
Изучаю SQL на примере из NetBeans туториала ConsultingAgency.Скрипт выдает ошибку

```
CREATE TABLE recruiter (
   recruiter_id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   client_name VARCHAR(50),
   client_department_number SMALLINT,
   CONSTRAINT recruiter_pk PRIMARY KEY ( recruiter_id )
);
```

Код ошибки 1064, положение SQL 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   password VARCHAR' at line 2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: какая СУБД используется?

Comment: это можно делать в mysql >= 5.7

Comment: Нужно использовать AUTO_INCREMENT???(MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

Жаль, что не указана, какая БД используется.
Но если рассматривать MySQL, то здесь явно ошибочное определение первичного ключа.
Следует использовать DDL в таком виде:

```
CREATE TABLE recruiter (
   recruiter_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   client_name VARCHAR(50),
   client_department_number SMALLINT,
   PRIMARY KEY ( recruiter_id )
);
```